# How can i measure the usage of my app? (i.e.: in Play Console)

Tags: android, tracking, measure, google-play-console

Is there a way to measure the usage (startups) of my android app?
In Play Console i only see the installations/deinstallations but not the startups etc.?

Well - i could implement a tracker on my own that access an interface on each startup - but i wonder if it's really necessary or if google provides that.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to add some sort of analytics.  There's a variety of libraries and backends for that.  Be aware that the one you particularly mention-  startups-  is a bad one to measure on Android.  Due to the application lifecycle, your app can be killed when in the background pretty much unconnected to the user actually wanting to exit.  I'd look at activity views or fragment views instead.